# A clever way to find nodes within a radius in a grid c#?

Tags: c#, grid

[image]

Suppose that we have a grid similar to the one in the image. The grid can also contain rectangular nodes. Now I want to find all the nodes within a radius same as illustrated on that image. A way of doing this is by checking all the nodes starting from `0,0`.

For each node I have to calculate the distance to node (`i,j`). This takes a lot of time especially if the number of nodes is huge.

There should be a better way to do this. Considering that I know the center of the `circle (node (i,j))` maybe I can develop a recursive function starting from i,j instead of checking each one of them.

Could you help me with a clever method for this purpose?

The distance measure is Euclidian Distance.

Comment: Thnx a lot for your answer. Im not actually asking for any code. A good algorithm/idea would be very helpful

Comment: Well, if nodes are of fixed dimension the first and simplest optimization that comes to my mind is to check only nodes that don't go outside a radius/maxSize. Let maxLambda = radius/maxSize; I am sure that nodes which have an X > X +maxLamba and X < X-maxLambda will not be contained inside the circle. this apply to Y too. If it's a grid it's probably contained in an array or similar data structure so it should be easy to get only the nearest node and check only on them.

Comment: Of course checking the whole matrix is stupid ^^. You could to a *hit test* with center of circle to find starting point. Then check connected nodes recursively until they fail hit test.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini I couldnt understand what are you refering to as maxSize?

Comment: @Sinatr I know the center in advance. im a little confused with that hit test :). Could you please be more precise becaue i couldnt get it :)

Comment: @user3148946 max size of a cell

Comment: @FabioMarcolini Ah nice. thnx a lot. it is considered as 1 unit. Algorithm is not depended on the size of the cell. thnx a lot for answering :)

Comment: @user3148946 for a recursive algorithm you probably could use a variation of [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either test all the cells inside the bounding box of the circle or, if you want to be a little more strict, perform a [breadth search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), using a queue-like data structure.

Comment: Yes I searched enough and for the matter of simplicity I will be using the nodes inside the bounding boxes. The nodes outside it which will be unnecessarily processed are a few and therefor not considerable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would be faster or slower computationally compared to the distance method you mentioned in your post, but Point-In-Polygon is a pretty common in computer science. It would be worth trying the ray-casting algorithm and see if it improves performance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon